# Where are these rock formations from macOS Big Sur and iOS 14.2?

Tags: mountain-identification

Where is this rock formation? This image is in macOS Big Sur and iOS 14.2 although by the looks of it I don't think it is from Big Sur since it is a coastal region. It is probably from somewhere else maybe Utah or Arizona?
[image]

Comment: It looks a bit like a set for a Star Trek episode...

Comment: It is probably from the Mojave Desert.The new wallpapers seem to be a mix of images from recent mac/iphone OSs, not just Big Sur. Look up "Mojave Desert colorful sandstone"

Answer (score 3):

This question has an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407229/113758).

The answer is [White Pocket, Vermilion Cliffs, Arizona](https://www.google.com/search?q=White+Pocket,+Vermilion+Cliffs,+Arizona&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 1):

According to [imore](https://www.imore.com/every-macos-wallpaper-revisited-real-life-and-captured-video), the background images are all related to the name of the OS. So, in your case this image will be somewhere in [Big Sur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Sur), which is a region in California. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Sur):

> Big Sur is a rugged and mountainous section of the Central Coast of California between Carmel Highlands and San Simeon, where the Santa Lucia Mountains rise abruptly from the Pacific Ocean. It is frequently praised for its dramatic scenery.

As this is quite a big area of land, where exactly in Big Sur it is taken is probably not easy to find, however it isn't impossible, as the people in the imore link above have managed to do it for a number of the OS's.

Apparently metadata is sometimes associated with the images, though most likely it has been scrubbed because of the sensitive nature of the environment, so they don't want hordes of people visiting each location with the concomitant problems. You may be able to access the metadata through preview, following the instructions  below from [macobserver](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/macos-use-preview-inspector-look-photo-metadata/), or using a photo editing program such as lightroom or GIMP:

> ```
> 1. Start by navigating to the image you want in Finder. Right click and select Open With Preview.
> 2. Next, click on Tools > Show Inspector in the menubar. You can also press ⌘ + I on your keyboard.
> 3. In the next window that pops up, click on the Exif tab. You’ll then see all of the pertinent information about your image.
> ```

Edited to add: The images you see for the OS have been heavily edited in professional-grade image processing software, so it is likely that the colours have been enhanced, shadows darkened or brightened, objects removed etc.